# SQL Как от текущей даты вычислить 1-ый день месяца с помощью формул, не прописывать вручную

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос, для примера:

```
drop table if exists #table_1
create table #table_1
(
day int, message varchar(500)
)
declare @day int
set @day=1
while @day <day(getdate())
begin
insert into #table_1 values(@day, 'Я есть грут')
set @day=@day+1
end
select * from #table_1
```

Используя цикл нужно записывать в таблицу с 1 числа (текущего месяца) до текущего числа (не включительно) каждый день фразу "Я есть грут"

Но в set я прописал вручную первое число set @day=1, как это высчитать с помощью формулы?

Comment: рекурсивный CTE не проще взять?

Comment: Дату нужно или день? Потому что 1-й день же всегда будет 1, зачем его вычислять то? ))

Comment: Да,  все верно, дату))

Answer (score 1):

**@day** - первый день текущего месяца

Насколько я понял вопрос, чтобы не писать **@day** каждый раз вручную, вы можете использовать такой запрос:

```
@day = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date),MONTH(@date),1)
```

или

```
@day = SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0)
```

или

```
@day = SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@date, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по синтаксису у вас SQL Server, а не MySQL.
Тогда так например:

```
drop table if exists #table_1
create table #table_1
(
day int, message varchar(500)
)

;with cte as(select 1 d union all select d+1 from cte where d+1 < day(getdate()))
insert #table_1
select d, N'Я есть грут' from cte

select * from #table_1
```

Ну если уж совсем рекурсия не нравится, можно извратиться так:

```
drop table if exists #table_1
create table #table_1
(
day int, message varchar(500)
)

insert #table_1
select row_number()over(order by(select 1)), N'Я есть грут'
from string_split(space(day(getdate())-2),' ')

select * from #table_1
```

:-)

или так, так ещё смешнее:

```
drop table if exists #table_1
create table #table_1
(
day int, message varchar(500)
)

;with f6 as(select*from(values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))f(f))
insert #table_1
select top(day(getdate())-1) row_number()over(order by(select 1)), N'Я есть грут'
from f6,f6 f

select * from #table_1
```

:-)

Comment: Все верно SQL Server, варианты неплохие, а если мне нужно выполнить задачу именно с использованием цикла while , подскажите?

Comment: @SON, так у вас решение в вопросе с циклом. Как бы ничего там особо и не придумаешь...

Comment: Я ж не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю, но если так, то ваш вариант мне больше нравится, спасибо